# UIImagePickerController presented from UIImageView inside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am having trouble loading a selected image from the UIImagePickerController inside a UIImageView. The UIImageView is presented on tap of a button that is inside a collectionViewCell. On tap of that button inside the collectionViewCell the UIImageView animates into view. On tap of that UIImageView the uiimagepicker is presented. The picker dismisses fine when an image is selected, but the image does not load inside the uiimageView on picker dismiss (the placeholder image remains and is not replaced by the selected image). No crashes or errors are occurring in my console. Thanks for any help!

**UICollectionViewCell** class - LoginCell

```
class LoginCell: UICollectionViewCell, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

lazy var createUsernameButton: UIButton = {
    let customButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    customButton.setTitle("Create Username", for: .normal)
    customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(animateIn), for: .touchUpInside)
    return customButton
}()

func animateIn() {
    addSubview(profileImageView)

    profileImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    profileImageView.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.profileImageView.alpha = 1
        self.profileImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }

}

    lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "avatar-bg-2x")
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImage)))
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return imageView
    }()

    var loginController: LoginController?

    func handleSelectProfileImage() {
        guard let loginController = delegate as? LoginController else {
            return
        }
        loginController.showImagePicker()
    }

//.....
}
```

**loginController** class

```
class LoginController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, LoginControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    weak var loginCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var loginCell: LoginCell?

    func showImagePicker() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        var selectedImageFromImagePicker: UIImage?

        if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromImagePicker = editedImage
        } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromImagePicker = originalImage
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromImagePicker {
                self.loginCell?.profileImageView.image = selectedImage
                print("was dismissed")
            }
        })
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let loginCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: loginCellId, for: indexPath) as! LoginCell
            loginCell.delegate = self
            return loginCell
    }
// ...
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `selectedImageFromImagePicker` is correct? It looks like it's coded such that it could be `nil`.

Comment: I believe it is not returning nil (a value shows up in the console for selectedImageFromPicker). Also this same code worked fine when I used it passing the selected Image to a UIImageView in a standard viewController. The difference with this case is the profileImageView is being presented inside a collectionViewCell (not a standard viewController).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, you are not updating the image on the main thread. Try this:

**1.** Change your code in the login controller class to match the code below.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    var selectedImageFromImagePicker: UIImage?

    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromImagePicker = editedImage
    } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromImagePicker = originalImage
    }

    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromImagePicker {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.loginCell?.profileImageView.image = selectedImage
            self.loginCollectionView.reloadData() //EDIT: add this new piece of code
        }
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

var profileImage: UIImage?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let loginCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: loginCellId, for: indexPath) as! LoginCell
        loginCell.delegate = self
        loginCell.profileImageView.image = profileImage != nil ? profileImage : UIImage(named: "avatar-bg-2x")
        return loginCell
}
```

**2.** Change this code in your loginCell class to match the code below.

```
lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    //removed line here
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImage)))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return imageView
}()
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Your logic and main thread definitely makes sense, but still is not working. I updated my original post to show maybe what was missing for better clarity on my end. I am wondering if it has something to do with how my UIImageView is presented... in my case I have the UIImageView being presented on top of the collectionViewCell via the animateIn() function. Not sure if that is causing problems ... ?

Comment: I actually thought of updating to that as well... still not working and with that update getting the "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Comment: Your logic is totally making sense and getting closer, but still not working and giving same fatal error.... hmmmmm ?

Comment: I just redid my logic of presenting the UIImageView to being presented inside a new viewcontroller class instead of inside a uiview on top of the collectionViewCell. That is a work around for now that accomplishes what I needed. Thanks for your insights and time though!